# Expo "Cannot GET /" when passing parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I have completely blank expo app. When I type on iPhone in safari deep link: exp://192.168.xxx.xxx:19000, it starts the app correctly.
When I try to pass parameter: exp://192.168.xxx.xxx:19000?param=test, it opens the expo app but with this error:

> `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>Error</title> </head> <body> <pre>Cannot GET /</pre> </body> </html>`

Comment: exp://192.168.xxx.xxx:19000?param=test isn't a value url structure. If you are passing parameters you need to specific the path first see https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/html-url.php

Comment: @DevWithZachary I understand. So basically this is valid url: ...:19000/path?param=test, but the app doesn't recognise entry point /path (I get error: Cannot get /path). How can I make expo app recognise that?